# php: importing multiple csv files into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
ini_set('display_errors', 'ON');

$host = "127.0.0.1"; // Host name
$username = "root"; // Mysql username
$password = ""; // Mysql password
$db_name = "test2"; // Database name
$tbl_name = "tcg_unique";

$con = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
$db_con = mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("cannot select DB");
$charset = mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);

$dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/Users/jacksons/Dropbox/MTG/SQL staging");
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($iterator as $file) {
echo $file, "\n";
if(strpos($file, '.csv') !== false){
mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file' INTO TABLE $tbl_name") or die (mysql_error());
}
else{
    print "else";
}
}
```

I am tying to load multiple csv files from a directory.  I am getting all the file path's to print out, but i am not able to get the data to load into the tables.  I tried one in mysql and it imported with no problem (all the column names matched).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

csv looks like:
cardname    vendor  condition   price   shipping    quantity    Date
Brimaz, King of Oreskos Game Citadel    Near Mint   18  0.5 4   5/30/14
Kiora, the Crashing Wave    FTW Games   Lightly Played  13.09   NA  1   5/30/14
Courser of Kruphix  Chicagoland Games   Near Mint   11.68   0.75    3   5/30/14

Comment: You're generating your LOAD DATA LOCAL query, but not actually running it - shouldn't it be inside a call to `mysql_query()`?

Comment: i had tried it like this orginally, but still getting no data

Comment: You need to use `mysql_query` to run it. Try `mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file' INTO TABLE '$tbl_name'") or die (mysql_error())` to see what error you get.

Comment: OK. So your code will either load your data; die with an error message; or print out `else`. What do you get?

Comment: sorry I think i messed up the comment ... It actually looks like its loading the files, but the fields are empty or null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is actually a csv file with fields separated by comma, you must specify the field separator.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '$file' INTO TABLE $tbl_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

If you don't state the field separator mysql considers the field separator as tab (\t).

In case the file is created with return carriage, monstly windows applications do that, you also need to add in the end of the statement:

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Comment: that did help, but the data is going in different than when i manually do one.  I can just hit import and it has everything set up right, but when i try it this way it leaves off the first column and which shifts everything to the left one.

Comment: Can you please post 3 or 4 lines of your csv file to your topic ? Thanks.

Comment: it isnt listing it right, but it is an excel file with "cardname vendor condition price shipping quantity" as the top of each column and the other stuff obviously goes in the corresponding column

Comment: ok i think it might have something to do with the "first line contains field names" box that i have checked when i import a single one.  also might need the other settings there

Comment: If you're exporting the files from excel you also need to add to the statement: "LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

Comment: sorry its a csv file ... was looking at it in excel

Comment: Is it generating any warnings/errors ? After the LOAD DATA statement execute the command "show warnings" and see what it shows.

Comment: i actually figured it out the other day and never updated ... i ended up having to include the "lines terminated by" and also "optionally enclosed by"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import several `csv` files and you're doing it *manually*, you might also want to use a graphical tool to make the job easier. You can use [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/) for this:

1. Access adminer from your browser.
2. Log in with admin rights.
3. Select your database.
4. Click on the `Import` option on the left.
5. Choose your `.csv` file.
6. Press the `Execute` button.